# sed '4!q' file name doesn't give proper result

Tags: sed, command-line

I have one file which is having 10 lines.
When I'm doing 
sed '4!q' filename
Why it's showing only first line?

Comment: May be you are looking for just `sed '4 q'`

Comment: `4!` means "not the 4th line", `q` means "print and quit" (unless the `-n` option is used). The first line is __not__ the 4th line, so `sed` prints it and quits ;-)

Comment: What did you expect it to do?

Comment: I thought it will print all lines because !q is there

Comment: If you're not doing `s/old/new` then you'd be better off using awk than sed. For example, to print the 4th line of input is just `awk 'NR == 4'`. To print all except the 4th line is `awk 'NR != 4'`. To print the first 4 lines is `awk 'NR <= 4'`. And so on. It couldn't be simpler.

Answer (score 1):

The `sed` expression `4!q` will execute the command `q` for each line that is not line 4, for example for the first line.

Executing `q` on the first line will cause the editing script to terminate after printing the contents of that line.

If you want to output the first four lines (it's unclear what you actually want to do), use either `head -n 4` or `sed 4q` ("quit at line 4").  If you want to print all but the 4th line, use `sed 4d` ("delete line 4").

Comment: How to `d`elete and `q`uite together? `sed '4{d;q}'` without using `head` or `tail`

Comment: @MamdouhSaeed You can't.  `d` will immediately discard the current line and start the next cycle, bypassing the `q`.  Swapping them around would immediately cause `q` to quit the current cycle, bypassing the `d`. It's unclear what effect you are looking for.

Comment: I'm using complicated `sed` with unmanaged pipe if I use `head` or `tail` it sometimes gets stuck. my code version now is the fastest possible and when I use `while read..` and execute some stuff line by line it works slower too

Comment: This still printing empty line too `seq 10|sed '4{s/4//;q10}'`

Comment: @MamdouhSaeed Yes, it would print an empty line for line 4, because you deleted the `4`.  What do you want with the `10` after `q`? (it would be ignored) It's still unclear what your intention is.